# How to scale Apache Camel route?

Tags: apache-camel

I have the following routes:

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <threadPoolProfile id="defaultProfile"
        defaultProfile="true" poolSize="100" maxPoolSize="200" />

    <route>
        <from uri="amq:example.MyQueue" />
        <setHeader headerName="myRoutingSlipHeader">
            <constant>amq:one#amq:two#amq:three#amq:four</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <log message="Makan" />
        <setExchangePattern pattern="InOut" />
        <routingSlip uriDelimiter="#">
            <header>myRoutingSlipHeader</header>
        </routingSlip>
        <setExchangePattern pattern="InOnly" />
        <log message="End: ${body}" />
    </route>

    <route>
        <from uri="amq:one" />
        <to uri="bean:helloBean?method=stepOne" />
    </route>

    <route>
        <from uri="amq:two" />
        <to uri="bean:helloBean?method=stepTwo" />
    </route>

    <route>
        <from uri="amq:three" />
        <to uri="bean:helloBean?method=stepThree" />
    </route>

    <route>
        <from uri="amq:four" />
        <to uri="bean:helloBean?method=stepFour" />
    </route>

    </camelContext>

<bean id="amq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent"
    p:brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" p:transacted="true"
    p:cacheLevelName="CACHE_CONSUMER" p:concurrentConsumers="20"
    p:maxConcurrentConsumers="500" p:idleConsumerLimit="10"
     />
```

Given that example.MyQueue is preloaded with 1000 messages, and each hello bean's step* methods takes 250ms, when I do camel:run, the performance is still bad. It prints "End: ..." each 1 secs in sequence not parallel. What would be the problem here?

In the following much simple case, I see a strange behavior. When there is no JMS producer putting messages into the queue, the printings happen in sequence. But when there is, the printings happen in parallel. What's the explanation?

```
<threadPoolProfile id="defaultProfile"
        defaultProfile="true" poolSize="100" maxPoolSize="200" />

<route>
  <from uri="amq:example.MyQueue" />
  <delay>
    <constant>1000</constant>
  </delay>
  <log message="End: ${body}" />
</route>

<bean id="amq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent"
    p:brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" p:transacted="true"
    p:cacheLevelName="CACHE_CONSUMER" p:concurrentConsumers="20"
    p:maxConcurrentConsumers="500" p:idleConsumerLimit="10"
     />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
   <from uri="amq:example.MyQueue" />
```

with

```
   <from uri="amq:example.MyQueue?concurrentConsumers=200&amp;maxConcurrentConsumers=500" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The routing slip runs in sequence, and yo do request/reply over JMS (eg the MEP is InOut) so processing one message would take

- call amq:one = 250 millis (request/reply)
- call amq:two = 250 millis (request/reply)
- call amq:three = 250 millis (request/reply)
- call amq:four = 250 millis (request/reply)

A total of 1 sec per message.

The AMQ route in < from > could process messages in parallel though. But each message would still take 1 second to process.

Comment: I know it. The problem is how to make it parallel?

Answer (score 0):

I guess routingSlip pattern is synchronized. you need something asynchronized component to handle this. Please check this:http://camel.apache.org/async.html

Just one question, why you need set the ExchangePattern?

Comment: Without ExchangePattern, result from the bean invocations won't be reflected in the last log.